# Request couchbase with two where conditions

Tags: sql, nosql, couchbase, sql++

How is it possible to write a couchbase request in order to choose the first condition in where if it is defined or the second one if the first one is undefined.

I tried somethings like :

```
SELECT id FROM auto as a WHERE IFMISSINGORNULL(ARRAY_LENGTH(a.data[0])>1, ARRAY_LENGTH(a.data[1])>1)
```

In this request if a.data[0] is defined, I want to check the length of a.data[0] and if a.data[0] is not defined, I want to check the length of a.data[1].

Comment: Is there a reason you can't write something of the form `WHERE (x = true AND foo) OR (x = false AND bar)`?

Comment: Something like 

```
SELECT id FROM auto as a 
WHERE (a.data[0] IS NOT NULL AND ARRAY_LENGTH(a.data[0])>1) OR (a.data[0] IS NULL AND ARRAY_LENGTH(a.records[1].changes.update_date)>1)
``` ??

Comment: Something of that form, yes. I don't quite understand why you're using `ARRAY_LENGTH`, though. Maybe it would be better to post a new question about what you're trying to query in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Condition should look as follows

```
WHERE ARRAY_LENGTH(IFNULL(a.data[0], a.data[1])) > 1
```

IFNULL(a.data[0], a.data[1])

- returns first argument if it is NOT NULL
- second argument when first    one is NULL